# Testing FormData submitted to fetch using jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm using Jest to test calling an API in my React app.

The code I'm testing is:

```
const createItem = (data) => {
  let formData = buildForm(data);

  return fetch(URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  });
};
```

I want to confirm that the `buildForm` function correctly converts the `data` to a `FormData` object.

My test looks like this:

```
it('creates item using api', () => {
  let data = {name: 'test name'};
  return createItem(data)
    .then(() => {
      let expForm = new FormData();
      expForm.append('name', data.name);

      expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(URL, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: expForm
      });
    });
});
```

The problem is, this test passes regardless what fields I append to `expForm` in my test. It seems like `toHaveBeenCalledWith` doesn't actually compare the values of `body` and just checks that it is a `FormData` object.

How can I test the values passed into the `body` FormData object?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can convert the FormData entries into an object for easy comparison.

```
expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  URL,
  expect.objectContaining({ method: 'POST', body: expect.any(FormData) })
);

const formData = Array.from(global.fetch.calls[0][1].body.entries())
  .reduce((acc, f) => ({ ...acc, [f[0]]: f[1] }), {});
expect(formData).toMatchObject(data);
```